Angular Server Side pagination using community edition and caching the data when navigating from other routes
I have implemented server side pagination using community edition based on this, I have a working example of server side pagination.
When I click on any column I navigate to different screen or different route which has the details of the row item. But when I click back from new route to previous route I am trying not to load the new set of data but render the previous data with all the grid settings.
Reference for server side pagination I used
https://medium.com/weekly-webtips/tech-building-reusable-server-side-pagination-for-ag-grid-in-angular-c8127e2da346
I Have created a sample application for performing server side pagination, I am able to render the users data and making API calls based on the change of pagination. I navigate to any page, and click on the row  and this navigates to new screen(route) which has user details and button to navigate back to GRID.
When I navigate back to GRID, rather than making API call again, I want to render previous cached data and also in the table if I was in page number 2 before navigating to user details screen, when I click back on user-details screen I should be on the same page 2 and page 1 and page 2 should be cached.
Server side pagination implementation example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/aggrid-server-side-pagination
Steps to Recreate or navigate

Load the AG-GRID angular server side pagination app
Click on 'Load Ag-Grid Table Data' button. this navigates and loads the table data
Navigate to page 2 and click on any row
Now the user page is loaded click on 'Back to Grid Table' button
On Table screen, currently it is loading the whole data instead we should render the cached data and the page number should be on page 2, and when I click previous page for pagination it should render cached page 1 data.

